# How to check the element is a member in f#?

Tags: f#

I am trying to compare list x with list S, if list x has all or some of the elements of S then the value is true else false. If x and S are empty then false as well. I am implementing the following code, unable to compile, hoping to find a solution. Appreciate it. Thank you:

```
let rec isMember x S =
match S with
|[] , [] -> false
|_ , [] -> true
|[] , _ -> false
|e1::rest1, e2::rest2 -> (e1=e2) || (isMember rest1 rest2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your match should include both lists (is a tuple), like this:

```
match x, S with
```

... although the way it is implemented `isMember` will only be true if `x` has more elements than `S` and the elements that `S` have are in the exact same order in `x`. You may want to use `List.contains`.

BTW, try and be consistent in your use of upper/lowercase, camel case is the convention in F#